# Restart css inheritance and hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a problem. In my web project I use css. In some moments I want to restart inheritance form the parent class.
I have some classes which define my styles, but I want to reset all style without hover.
When I use reset in this way:

```
<a id="hrefSite" href="{{route('about') }}"><i style="all: unset; font-size: 150px;" class="conf conf-ui"></i></a>
```

It works, but when I add `color: #868e96;` in style inline, the hover dosn't work.
These two classes *conf conf-ui* must stay because there I load the google, fb, etc icons.
I tried write another class to do it:

```
.newStyle{
    all: unset; !important;
    font-size: 150px;
    color: #868e96;
}

<a id="hrefSite" href="{{route('about') }}"><i class="conf conf-ui newStyle"></i></a>
```

but it isn't working correctly. Size is incorrect.

EDIT:
This is my hierarchy in HTML.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
   <div class="cr">
       <div class="cr-block cntr"
           <div class="icon">
              <a id="hrefSite" href="{{route('about') }}"><i class="conf conf-ui newStyle"></i></a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add in a code snippet? It's difficult to visual what exactly you've implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.
I tried to set style to `<i>` tag. When I changed it for `<div>` tag it works.
But now I don't now why. 
It's due to that in css I can't set style for `<i>` tag?
Can someone explain this?